# flutter - The problem that the app runs internally when a push message is received even when it is terminated

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

[ Steps to reproduce the behavior ]

1. Swipe in ios to quit the app.
2. Even if it is terminated, initstate() is called internally when a push message is received.

I didn't see any explanation that the app runs internally in the terminated state when a push is received.
The app seems to start internally
Is this a bug?
Or is it normal?

If this is normal, how can i distinguish it from what a user executes?

Comment: How have you implemented push notifications in your app?

Comment: I saw https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications and implemented it.